# Accessing parent scope from isolated scope

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to write attribute directive that wraps element and decorates it with some other things along with additional directives. And I need to keep content inside the element intact. Something like this:

```
app.controller 'myCtrl', ($scope)->
  $scope.name = "Gwendolyn"

app.directive 'niceName',($compile)->
  restrict: 'A'
  replace: yes
  scope: niceName:"="
  template: (element, attrs)->
      "<div> 
           <div style='background:lightgray'> 
                #{element.html()}                
           </div>
           <div> 
              <h1>{{nice}}</h1>
           </div>
       </div>"

  controller: ($scope, $element)->
    $scope.$watch 'hover',->
      $scope.nice = if $scope.hover then $scope.niceName else ''

  compile:(element, attrs)->
     element.attr('ng-mouseover',"hover = true")
     element.attr('ng-mouseout',"hover = false")
     element.removeAttr('nice-name') # removing itself to avoid from falling into infinite loop

     pre:(scope, iElement, iAttrs)->
        $compile(iElement)(scope)
```

Markup:

```
<div nice-name="uglyname">
   <h2>{{uglyname}}</h2>
<div>
```

Now that thing doesn't work at all, it won't render `h2` part because now `uglyname` is unknown to the current scope. I can compile it with passing the parent scope, but then it totally breaks my controller. (see jsbin below)
So somehow I have to compile content of the element applying parent scope, add it to the template and then compile again applying local scope? Or I need to find a way to inherit properties of parent scope? Or I can't do it with attribute directive? Maybe I need to use element directive and transclusion?
Any ideas?

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lomodife/3/)

Answer (score -1):

i would do what @marfarma suggested as well as change you html to not include the brackets so:

```
 scope: { niceName: "="},
```

and

```
 nice-name="uglyname"
```

Comment: Ah, yes.  The attribute markup is wrong too.  Good catch

Comment: With fixing that I have new problems... can you check updated question?